# While loop is causing items to disappear

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, while-loop

I am working on an Android project using c# and xamarin (Visual Studio). My idea is to mute the phone whenever it connects to a wifi. So I have one textview and one button and those are my codes till now:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.GetNetworkInfo(ConnectivityType.Wifi);
            while (mWifi.IsConnectedOrConnecting)
        {
            audioManager.RingerMode = RingerMode.Silent;
        }
```

My codes are working great but with some bugs: When the phone is connected to wifi, it mute but also all my items in my layout are disappearing. And when the phone is not connected to wifi, it doesn't mute but all my items are still in their place. Why is this happening ?
In addition, I want the program to run in the background so that whenever the phone is connected to a wifi, it mute. To do that I have created this service class but it doesn't seems to work:

```
  [Service]
public class DemoService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Log.Debug("DemoService", "Doing work");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Log.Debug("DemoService", "Work complete");
            StopSelf();
        }
        );
        t.Start();
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: If the first code block is executed from a UI event it will block the interface, you have a blocking loop in the case `IsConnectedOrConnecting` is true (also, the code will never exit the loop as you don't refresh the `NetworkInfo` instance and will always have the same value).

Comment: I have understand. How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: @WassimDernayka Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BroadcastReceiver` to receive  action: `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE` to detect the connecting or connected.

WifiReceiver.cs:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled =true)]
[IntentFilter( new [] { "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"})]
public class WifiReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       NetworkInfo info=intent.GetParcelableExtra(WifiManager.ExtraNetworkInfo) as NetworkInfo;
        if (info != null && info.IsConnected)
        {

            ConnectivityManager manager =(ConnectivityManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = (NetworkInfo)manager.GetNetworkInfo(ConnectivityType.Wifi);
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);

            if (netInfo.IsConnectedOrConnecting)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Wifi is connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                audioManager.RingerMode = RingerMode.Silent;
            }
            else
            {
                audioManager.RingerMode = RingerMode.Normal;
            }

        }
    }
}
```